# What is the easiest way to get: $2+ \sqrt{-121} = (2+ \sqrt{-1})^3$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was reading the book *Seventeen equations have changed the world*.
At some point, while the book was talking about complex numbers, I see this equation:

$2+ \sqrt{-121} = (2+ \sqrt{-1})^3$

Even if it's easy to **proof the truth** of this equivalence (it is enough to develop the two members),
I can't find an easy/good/fast way to obtain straight the identity.

Can you help me? Does there exist a mathematical property that I'm missing?

Comment: You could note that the *norm* of $2+\sqrt{-121}=2+11\sqrt{-1}$ is $2^2+11^2=125=5^3$, which implies that $2+\sqrt{-121}=\alpha^3$ where the norm of $\alpha$ is $5$.

Comment: @Servaes But you would also need $\tan\left(\frac{\arctan(11/2)}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$. Is this easy to see?

Comment: @kccu I have no idea why you would need that.

Comment: I am given $2+\sqrt{-121}$ and I want to write it in some other form. I notice it has norm $5^3$, so it is $\alpha^3$ for some $\alpha$ with norm $5$. How do I know $\alpha = 2+i$? I need to know the argument of $2+\sqrt{121}$, and the $\sin$ and $\cos$ of this argument divided by $3$.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-i-find-the-cube-root-of-a-complex-number

Comment: Thus, does not exist a simple reverse formula? Or a sum of cubes? In order to get that result $(2+i)^3$, you have to use a trial-and-error method, that's right?

Comment: @kccu No, I need to solve $a^2+b^2=5$, which has the clear solution $a=2$, $b=1$, and three others, but comparing signs already shows that this is the only solution.

Comment: @mattia.b89 My answer shows a method that is not purely trial and error. And what do you mean by a reverse formula?

Comment: formula such as binomials

Comment: @Servaes Right, I was missing that we only needed to look for *integer* solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the product as
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2+\sqrt{-1})^3&=&2^3+3\times2^2\sqrt{-1}+3\times2\sqrt{-1}^2+\sqrt{-1}^3\\
&=&(2^3-6)+(3\times2^2-1)\sqrt{-1}\\
&=&2+11\sqrt{-1}\\
&=&2+\sqrt{-121},
\end{eqnarray*}
is so elementary that I cannot think of any easier way to show it.

But suppose you want to determine the factorization of $2+\sqrt{-121}$, i.e. roughly speaking an expression
$$2+\sqrt{-121}=(a_1+b_1\sqrt{-1})(a_2+b_2\sqrt{-1})\cdots(a_n+b_n\sqrt{-1}),$$
where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are *integers*. This is the subject of algebraic number theory. I will use a few results without mention, as I don't know your background in the subject. You could note that the *norm* equals
$$N(2+\sqrt{-121})=N(2+11\sqrt{-1})=2^2+11^2=125=5^3,$$
and that $5$ does not divide $2+\sqrt{-121}$. This implies that
$$2+11\sqrt{-1}=(a+b\sqrt{-1})^3,$$
where the norm of $a+b\sqrt{-1}$ equals $5$. This means that
$$5=N(a+b\sqrt{-1})=a^2+b^2,$$
which has the solutions
$$1+2\sqrt{-1},\qquad 1-2\sqrt{-1},\qquad 2+\sqrt{-1},\qquad 2-\sqrt{-1}.$$
It is then a quick check to show that only $2+\sqrt{-1}$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you approached it before.

If you want to utlise the binomial expansion
$$
(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\matrix{n\\k}\right)x^ky^{n-k}
$$
then we have
$$
\begin{align}
(x+y)^3 &= \left(\matrix{3\\0}\right)2^3 +\left(\matrix{3\\1}\right)2^2\sqrt{-1} + \left(\matrix{3\\2}\right)2^1(\sqrt{-1})^2  + \left(\matrix{3\\3}\right)(\sqrt{-1})^3 \\
&= 2^3 + 3\cdot 2^2\sqrt{-1} + 3\cdot 2\cdot-1 + \sqrt{-1}\cdot(\sqrt{-1})^2\\
&=8+12\sqrt{-1} -6 -\sqrt{-1} = 2 +11\sqrt{-1} = 2 + \sqrt{11^2\cdot - 1} \\
&=2+\sqrt{-121}
\end{align} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

The development *is* easy.

Mentally,

$$(2+i)^3=8-6+i(12-1).$$

I can't see any shortcut. (Of course, the identity in the book was established from the right.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is to prove:
$$2+11i=2+i+10i=2+i+(2+i)(2+4i)=(2+i)(3+4i)=(2+i)(2+i+1+3i)=(2+i)(2+i+(2+i)(1+i))=(2+i)(2+i)(2+i).$$